# Capistrano cannot read from remote repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, capistrano

since recently, I have an issue when deploying my Rails app with Capistrano:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG[4a3de544]     fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I can push to my remote repository, but when I run the command:

```
ssh -vvv git@github.com
```

I'm seeing this error messages in the output:

```
Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: Do you have a key in Users/usernames/.ssh?

Comment: @NickM, yes I have id_rsa and id_rsa.pub key. I can also do a passwordless ssh into my production server.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that capistrano is connecting as a different user than **you** do when you SSH into the server.

The message you got is unambiguous.  I assume you anonymized it for this post; you are NOT connecting as "username".

Comment: Hi Thom, yes, I anonymized my username.